# beginner: Discord bot problems - AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'display_name'

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, attributes, non-type

```
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import Bot

bot = Bot(command_prefix='$')
intents = discord.Intents().all()
TOKEN = 'changeditforexample'

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Bot connected as {bot.user}')


@bot.command(name='server')
async def fetchserverInfo(ctx):
    guild = ctx.guild

    await ctx.send(f'Server Name: {guild.name}')
    await ctx.send(f'Server Size: {len(guild.members)}')
    await ctx.send(f'Server owner: {guild.owner.display_name}')


bot.run(TOKEN)
```

**The actual error.**

> discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'display_name'

So my question is how do i make it work? it only **shows the server has 1 member which is wrong** i have 3 accounts in there and **the {guild.owner.display_name}** doesn't seem to work.

i'm pretty new to python and coding in general so it might just be really simple i just can't figure it out. *i did see an example which showed this should work* **but it doesn't**

I'm using

- discord.py 1.7.2
- python 3.9
- newest version of pycharm

[Error + Bot results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h480K.png)

Answer (score 0):

Currently, your intents aren't being passed to the Bot constructor, therefore they aren't taking effect. The proper way to enable intents is:

```
bot = Bot(command_prefix='$', intents=discord.Intents.all())
```

`Intents.all()` is also [a class method](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Intents.all) which is why you don't need the parentheses after `Intents`

Comment: Thanks man! i was accidentally following old guides before on the basics and learned some outdated stuff this helped and fixed everything. first i got the error that linked my to the dev page of Discord where i had to turn on SERVER MEMBERS INTENT and PRESENCE INTENT. thanks a lot mate :) back to learning.. i need more rep to upvote you but i did press it